# Ubuntu machine time issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, time, ntp

New to ubuntu. I see that my machine has wrong time set in the system. Can some one help how to correct the system time.

```
timedatectl shows
      Local time: Tue 2019-07-16 03:53:00 IST
  Universal time: Mon 2019-07-15 22:23:00 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2019-07-15 22:23:00
       Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

where as the actual date is **Mon 2019-07-15 22:55:00 IST**.
checking when the sync has happened, but the command shows

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
           └─disable-with-time-daemon.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Tue 2019-07-16 02:44:11 IST; 1h 6min ago
           ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/ntpd was not met
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8).
```

How do i fix the system time now?

Comment: System time for all timezones is ahead by 5 hours.  I corrected the question

Answer (score 1):

If the machine is dual-booted between Windows and Linux, you have to tell Linux to use the hardware clock in local time(*):

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock
```

In other situations, you can figure out if the hardware clock in in UTC or local time with:

```
sudo hwclock --localtime 
sudo hwclock --utc
```

The one that gives the right answer is the one used by the hardware clock.

(*) On Unix systems, the hardware clock is normally in UTC, conversion to local time is done only when displaying things. Windows does otherwise...

Comment: No this is not dual booted. Its a ubuntu virtual machine

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: i changed the ntp server in /etc/ntp.conf file. I was using ntp server from ubuntu pool which was giving me wrong time, Used one defined at my company and it started to work fine

Comment: Your company has  strange time servers...